# Using header of chunk to save plot

Tags: r, plot, knitr

So I've been searching for an answer for this, and haven't really found anything.  I'm hoping there isn't anything like this already on the board so I don't waste anyone's time.  In the recent upgrade of I'm assuming RStudio, a method I used to save plots went away.  Below is an example chunk of what it looks like:

````
```{r dummy, dev=c('png', 'pdf'), fig.height=4, fig.width=6}

x = 1:10
y = 10:1

plot(x,y)
```
````

The code will still compile when I do this.  However, when I knit my code in order to save the plots, it does not save the plots.  Is there a way similar to this that is compatible with the updated RStudio/knitr?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: you can add the `self_contained: no` option in the html_document output front matter section at the top of your Rmd. but the images are embedded in the html so you dont really need the images folder

Comment: @user2221184 You can copy the comment above, post it as the answer, and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add the self_contained: no option in the html_document output front matter section at the top of your Rmd. but the images are embedded in the html so you dont really need the images folder –  rawr

EDIT:

like so:

```
---
output:
  html_document:
    self_contained: no
    <other options>
---

res of knitr document...
```

this will generate a couple new directories and within the "figure-html" one, you can find the images.