# Cache folder for figures deletes itself after knitting html/pdf on RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

This problem just seems weird to me: I have several plots and tables being produced in my RMarkdown doc, so I'd like to cache to save on compiling/knitting time. When I change all of the cache options to cache=TRUE, it creates two folders in my directory: "Figures_Full_Study_cache" and "Figures_Full_Study_figures" as it should. Problem is, while the former (_cache) remains, the latter (_figures) deletes itself after compiling.

As it's happening, I can see both the "Figures_Full_Study_cache" and "Figures_Full_Study_figures" folders being created. I can even go into the "Figures_Full_Study_figures" folder and see each individual .png being produced in real time. However, once Markdown/pandoc is done, the "Figures_Full_Study_figures" file is immediately deleted (I have screenshots of all of this, but I'm too new to stack overflow to post images).

Of course, once this file disappears along with the .png images, R generates an error when I try to run it again using cache=TRUE because those files don't exist (the tables work just fine). Any ideas why my cached file is deleting itself? I've included a representative example of how my plots are made using ggplot2 and entered into RMarkdown:

````
```{r,echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, fig.width=5,fig.height=3.5,cache=TRUE}
     ggplot(Demographics, aes(x=Exp)) +
     geom_histogram(binwidth=2,fill="slateblue1", color="black", alpha=.9) +
     theme_general # Defined previously, not relevant to this discussion
     # My apologies for not being able to post the data... protected research.
```
````

And here are the options for the Markdown doc in case needed:

```
---
title: "Figures Full Study"
author: "Name"
date: "Wednesday, August 13, 2014"
output:
  html_document: default
---
```

Comment: [the self_contained option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24857264/using-header-of-chunk-to-save-plot)

Comment: This did not work: Putting "self_contained: no" in the front matter did not solve the problem, btw. R is still creating a file, then deleting it.

Comment: post a small example with a plot and your front matter

Comment: This is another answer on SO on the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24916054/3082472